# How can I serve the static dist folder as my front end in a Spring Boot server?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-mvc, angular-routing

I have written my server code in spring, and had written the front end code in angular.

Now I am unable to serve both of them to single port.

I have built the dist folder and placed it in the static folder in spring directory, but the angular routing is not working.

I think this is not the perfect way to do this. I have looked for various resources and gone through many articles but still I am unable to get the perfect solution.

Comment: how about using external tomcat server and deploy both application separate, this way you can run them on single port

Comment: using a nginx proxy_pass you can do that as well on the same server else what Shailesh said deploy separate. It totally depends on your architecture choice. both of them are widely used strategies

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am a newbie to Spring, can you please share some links.